# "No such module 'Firebase'" when add Firebase into a library

Tags: xcode, swift, firebase, cocoapods

I just created new Framework and added Firebase via CocoaPods, when combine the library it success.

But when I add that library to other project via CocoaPods as well, then combine that project, and it raise an error: `No such module 'Firebase'`

Anyone faced a problem like this?

Comment: Can you post your podspec so we can see how you're integrating this? Also, how are you installing this in your app? Can you run `pod spec lint` on your library and post the output of that?

Comment: I am facing the same issue, do we solution for it ?

Answer (score 17):

You need to add the follwing to your POD file:

`pod 'Firebase'`

After that, you need to type in your terminal

`pod install` (to refresh the pod file)

Comment: This worked for me, I was using Xcode 10.2 and upgraded to 10.3 and Firebase needed update

Answer (score 9):

Everything was setup fine and was working before but..

**My Problem**:

[image]

**What's was wrong with me?**

- I was using older name of pod, eg. - `pod 'Firebase/Analytics'`, `pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'`
- New pod names are `pod 'FirebaseAnalytics'`, `pod 'FirebaseCrashlytics'` (Problem with `/` )
  [image]

**Solution:**

- Use new pod name to integrate `pod 'FirebaseAnalytics'`, `pod 'FirebaseCrashlytics'` (Install pod with new pod name)
- Import `import FirebaseCore`, `import FirebaseAnalytics` instead just `import Firebase`
- `import FirebaseAnalytics` - I'm using for log events

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Do you open the workspace file after installed with cocoa pods ?

Check if the library is added in "Linked Frameworks" or "Embedded Binaries"

[image]

If it didn't work, add this pod file

```
platform :ios, '8.0' use_frameworks! target ‘Your Project’ do


pod 'Firebase', '>= 2.5.1'
pod ‘Firebase/Auth’
pod ‘Google/SignIn’
pod ‘Firebase/Database’
pod 'Firebase/Storage' end
```

and then type `pod deintegrate` and after that run `pod install`.

Comment: Click on .xcodeproj in hierarchy and try to linked the right embedded library.

Comment: Bad. 
Show me your podfile ?

Comment: source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!
inhibit_all_warnings!

target 'FirebaseAPI' do
   pod 'Firebase'
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/Crash'
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'
    pod 'Firebase/Database'
end

Comment: Thanks a lot! The command which you mentioned should be pod deintegrate instead of pod -reintegrate

Answer (score 8):

I solve my problem using just the specific `import` that I'm using, for example.
In my SDK I'm using FirebaseCore and FirebaseAnalytics.
Into my class I just import:

```
import FirebaseCore
import FirebaseAnalytics
```

And in my .podspec I needed to set `static_framework` property to true, so my .podspec it's seems like code below:

```
s.static_framework = true

s.dependency 'Firebase'
s.dependency 'Firebase/Core'
```

It works for me!

Answer (score 7):

this is the easiest solution nowadays
[image: Step 1]

*`<XCode_Project_Folder>`>General>Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content: `FirebaseAuth`*

[image: Step 2]

Answer (score 4):

tried all these..
I was stuck in this situation for more than 2weeks.

finally resolved by adding "excluded architectures = arm64"

[image]

Comment: Yep, that worked for me. Thanks. Btw to find this info in the project, select the project name (top line) in the navigator on the left

Comment: Thank you! I waste half of the day solving that problem!

Comment: What does excluding arm64 do though? What other implications does it have in doing this. You may have solved the problem, but without context and documentation how do we know this won't cause other issues or have other unintended consequences?

Answer (score 1):

Hi today i fix same problem
1 : open podfile from xcode than add " pod 'Firebase' "
save and close it
2 : open vscode or any editor using, open new terminal than write " cd ios " to open ios file than " pod install " when you install it showing problem need to add search path
so now open ios file from xcode and go to : runner > target runner > build settings > all > search paths
and add this " $(inherited) " into framework search path and header search path
that's all

Answer (score 1):

**This issue can be caused by incorrectly set-up schemes:**

If you have multiple schemes (e.g. 'Dev', 'QA', 'Production' etc.) in your project, check you have the build configurations set correctly.

Further guidance in this answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65453578/12322900

Then run `pod deintegrate` and `pod install` and make sure you're using the `.xcworkspace` file.

Comment: Thanks for this comment. I kept getting "No such module 'Firebase'" or "No such module: 'Flutter'". My setup had multiple schemes corresponding to app flavors. I set the correct build configurations to the flavours in `Product` > `Scheme` > `Manage Schemes` > (select and edit your scheme flavor) > Review all tabs setting the correct Build Configuration e.g. `Release-{flavor}`

Comment: Just ran into this problem again, glad I made and came back to this comment. In my case, the Achive configuration reset itself to "Release-production" and not "Release-{flavor}" causing this same issue.

Answer (score 0):

For me I had to change the version specified in the Podfile as it was above what my app supported. Specifically in the Podfile I changed: `'platform :ios, '11.0'` to platform :ios, '10.0' which corresponds with Deployment Info in the General Tab for my app I'm working on.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For Flutter folks adding Firebase to their apps, make sure you follow the steps in [Add Firebase to your iOS Project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup) as well as those in the SDK setup steps in the Firebase Console:

[image]

In summary:

1. Run `pod init` if you don't have a pod file
2. Add the necessary pods to the bottom of the podfile. All possible Firebase pods can be found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#available-pods).

   pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
   pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
   pod 'Firebase/Auth'
   pod 'Firebase/Storage'
3. Run `pod install`

Answer (score 0):

My failure was that I downloaded modules to

```
  target 'YourProjectUITests' do
    # Pods for testing
       pod 'FirebaseCore'
```

And the right one is

```
  # Pods for YourProject
    pod 'FirebaseCore'
```

(Without UITests)

Answer (score -1):

It is because you don't have added pod dependency in Podfile.

you will find below line in Podfile

Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
#platform :ios, '9.0'

follow the below steps.

1)**just remove the # .so it will be like.**

platform :ios, '9.0'

2)**add the below dependencies.**(Do not add all ,you just need to add whatever used in you app ,if you have used Firebase/Core only then add that line only)

#Pods for app name

pod 'Firebase'

pod 'Firebase/Core'

pod 'Firebase/Auth'

pod 'Firebase/Database'

3)**clean the build**

flutter clean

4)run Command :

flutter run (It will automatically adds a required pods).

that's it.

Answer (score -2):

The same thing happened to me last week. I solved it by:

```
1. pod deintegrate
2. Open Xcode and delete any instance of pod.
3. pod install
```