# No such module 'Firebase'” when add Firebase into a dynamic framework

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I just created new Framework and added Firebase via CocoaPods, when build the framework it succeed.

But when I add that framework to other project via CocoaPods as well, then build project, and it raise an error: **No such module 'Firebase'**

I have added dependency to .podspec file, but still same error
spec.dependency "Firebase"

Anyone can help me please ?

I know this question is there on stack overflow but no solution provided
["No such module 'Firebase'" when add Firebase into a library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37850498/no-such-module-firebase-when-add-firebase-into-a-library)

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to add `Firebase` as a dependency to other podspecs. It's a [wrapper pod](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/Firebase.podspec) for other pods only and is useful so that Podfile users can get any Firebase modules imported with a single `import Firebase`.

podspec's should depend on the specific Firebase pods needed.