# flutter project not making build in xcode getting this error No such module 'Flutter' while its proper set

Tags: flutter, flutter-ios-build

flutter project not making build in Xcode getting this error `No such module 'Flutter'` while its proper set.

I have tried to run with the command line set flutter path then flutter clean, flutter pub get, then go to ios folder and run pod install, pod update and run flutter build ios. but getting

> Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): No such module 'Firebase'
> /Applications/Jaydev_LMS%20/All_Flutter/SockerApp_Client%20/soccergeeks-mobileApp/ios/Runner/AppDelegate.swift:2:7

Comment: The error is "No such module Firebase" and not Flutter, please check answers on this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37850498/no-such-module-firebase-when-add-firebase-into-a-library

Comment: this could be due to google-services-info.pist file, added manually, insteat you should add it using xcode only.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this [doc](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/manual-installation/ios). I think you followed IOS installation from firebase instructions and you added `import Firebase` in `AppDelegate.swift` file. But you have to follow above-mentioned doc. It does not mentioned to modified `AppDelegate.swift` file.